# downloading huge csv file from hadoop having more than 5 million rows

Tags: csv, hadoop

I have to download data from `hadoop`(using HIVE editor) having more than 5 million rows . i tried to download in `csv` file format but downloaded file does not allow more than 1 million rows. how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hue will not perform well for downloading and streaming a lot of data to a browser as it is not designed for that. Hue is lightweight.

Please check this JIRA : https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2142

Answer (score 0):

If you data is in a hive table you can just to a hadoop fs -get from the location where the data is lying